# radio-like streaming server Elixir plug&cowboy

Tags: streaming, elixir

I want to build a radio server in Elixir, my current code using plug & cowboy (thank to @rozap) stream an audio file to a browser client

```
defmodule Plugtest do
  import Plug.Conn

  @chunk_size 128
  @song_path "./song.mp3"
  @content_type "audio/mpeg"
  @status_code 200

  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(conn, opts) do
    conn = conn
    |> send_chunked(@status_code)
    |> put_resp_content_type(@content_type)

    File.stream!(@song_path, [], @chunk_size)
    |> Enum.into(conn)
  end
end

IO.puts "streaming @ http://localhost:4000"
Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.http Plugtest, []
```

I want this server to work and play the songs from a playlist
( for this test looping song.mp3 is fine )
and save the current chunk so each new user will listen from this chunk
and that will make all users hear from the same second, like a regular radio server, how can I make this happen ?

Comment: I tried to write a process that reads from file in a loop and another process that manage the connections and stream to them

Comment: And what didn't work for you? "How to write something" is an open ended question. It would be better if you post your implementation and in case something doesn't work just ask why.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question is how to approach this problem of handling connections and stream the same chunk to all connected users, didn't get far in coding, I want to understand the elixir's way of solving this issue before

Comment: @tkowal please check new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551798